# MVC4 C# Membership registration role depending on which button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roles, membership

I'm creating a site in MVC4, which is the first time I've use MVC in .NET,  I've sussed out the logging in and registration.  I have this scenario:

The website has Role 'A' and Role 'B', when a user hasn't registered before I want to direct them to the registration page, when they click on the Register section on their specific section, I direct them to the registration page.  However I want the registration page to automatically define their role, based on which Registration button they clicked.

So a user clicks button 'A' when they register they will be assigned Role 'A', and when Agent 'B' registers they are automatically assigned Role 'B'.  I want to avoid get variables to stop people overriding the selection.

Comment: What have you done so far? You need to provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways how you can implement it. For example:

add `bool IsAgentA` to your `RegisterModel class` in `AccountModels.cs`

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public bool IsAgentA {get; set;}
    }
```

Add radio buttons for `IsAgentA` in your `Registration View` (Yes - Agent A, No - Agent b). I will not write it here.

And after that modify your `Register ActionResult` in `AccountController` as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                    if (model.IsAgentA)
                    {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Role A"); // user in role A 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Role B"); // user in role B
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although it is an answer, I wanted to do this autonomously so the user didn't have to select.  It was one of those scenario's I spend to long working on one thing.  Having took a break over the weekend, I've seen the light.  Basically the user clicks the register button on there section, which goes to the controller, which then sets a session variable, and Bobs my uncle :)